# Kubuntu 11.10 Internet Sharing via Wireless

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kubuntu

I just setup fresh kubuntu 11.10. I have a wired internet in my apartment but need to do wireless internet sharing from kubuntu (laptop i using) to another mac book pro. I can't find the solution that match what I need. Anyone have some good guide or solution :) for this.

Comment: Can you describe what you need?

Comment: Sorry for short description. What i need is to share internet connection from labtop( kubuntu ) for other labtop through wireless. My kubuntu machine has internet connection from wired internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a wireless access point.

If you have a Kubuntu machine that will act as a router you will need to configure the wireless interface to act as an access point and have `iptables` to provide firewall and NAT services and laptop will connect to that access point.

If your router is acting as a wireless access point and then you connect it directly to the router from the laptop.